# How import a badly formatted csv file into a postgresql table

Tags: postgresql

I've got a csv file which has a format problem :

```
first column,second column,third column,fourth column
col1,col2,col3,col4
a1,b1,c1,d1
a2,,c2,d2
a3,b3
a4,b4,c4,d4
```

When i want import in a postgresql table with

```
\copy public.import FROM PROGRAM 'more +1 \"file.csv\"' DELIMITER ',' ENCODING 'UTF8' CSV HEADER"
```

i have the error message "missing data for column "col3"

with csv file

```
first column,second column,third column,fourth column
col1,col2,col3,col4
a1,b1,c1,d1
a2,,c2,d2
a3,b3,,
a4,b4,c4,d4
```

no problem.

How to solve this problem without modifying the csv ?

I work with postgresql 9.4

Thanks for your help